# Youtube YouTubePlayerSupportFragment not work correctly (loading always?)

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I have a problem with YouTube (always loading).

Apparently works correctly "but only first time", I want say, the first instance (first run) works correctly and load correctly horitzontal and vertically, but when change fragment - > `fragmentManager.beginTransaction()` in my MainActivity (I have function on all fragments calls this method to `beginTransaction`) , and after I go to - > beginTransaction YouTube - > the video always load:

Example:

**Step 1**

First time - > MainActivity - > beginTransaction YouTube - > click - -> Load 
correctly

**Step 2**

Second time - > MainActivity - > beginTransaction YouTube - > click - -> Load always

Close App (Menu) and repeat Step 1 and 2 .

This is my code :

```
public void youtube(){

        youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();

        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
                    youTubePlayers=youTubePlayer;
                }
                // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                youTubePlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFullscreen(boolean b) {
                        if(b){
                            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            MainActivity.isYoutubeReadyHoritzontal=true;
                            knowIfPortraitAndBackManyally=0;
                        }else {
                            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                            knowIfPortraitAndBackManyally=1;
                            MainActivity.countIFexit=0;
                            //MainActivity.isYoutubeReadyHoritzontal=false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
                if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                    errorReason.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
                } else {
                    String errorMessage = String.format("YouTube Error (%1$s)",
                            errorReason.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        });


        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.youtube_fragment,youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
        MainActivity.isYoutubeReadyHoritzontal=true;

}
```

XML

```
<FrameLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

                        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment" >
```

Comment: I pass to activity http://javatechig.com/android/youtubeplayerview-example-in-android-using-youtube-api but horitzontal not work

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior since today

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was caused by a failure to properly dispose of a previous player instance. Make sure to call `youTubePlayer.release()` when it's no longer needed.